# QGIS georeference raster to world file (WLD)

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference a raster (jpg). I can easily create a geotiff, but when trying to use the QGIS georeferencer to create a wld file instead, something goes wrong. 
I have the target CRS set, and using liniar, the wld file is created.
But when I load into QGIS an error pops up and says the wld file contains no CRS, and thus the raster loads into the standard CRS (which is not the CRS I had to georeference the raster to). Anybody knows which knob I need to switch on or off? I can find plenty of pages explaining how to georef to geotiff, but this one I cannot find.

EDIT: I was following the guide here:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html

first for the geotif, and then I tried to modify settings to save as a world file. 
I set to liniar, set target crs to 4044 as pr the instruction on the page. But as was said, this is not saved to worldfile. and then I checked create world file. all filenames for .wld, .point and .jpg are identical.

using QGIS 2.14

Comment: World files never contain any information about the projection. Sometimes projection is saved into a separate file (.prj or .xml, for example) but I do not how QGIS behaves. But if you add tiff+tfw into QGIS project the CRS selector window should open and you can give the correct CRS there.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain an example of the exact file names you are populating for the image, the world file, and the coordinate reference information.

Comment: The conventional form for a world file of a .jpg is ".jpw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu, choose `Settings -> Options -> CRS`. Under `CRS for new layers`, you can select `Prompt for CRS`.

That way you always will be asked for the CRS, and not assigned a default.

If you have a shapefile in the same CRS, you can duplicate the .prj file to the name of the raster. Then QGIS can read that to load the raster without prompting.

Comment: I don't know if this really is the issue. but I ran through the process again, just this time I did what you suggested and got the prompt. The prompt also came when opening the raster in the georeference tool. this time the world file worked as expected. 
Thanks...